# Error Trying to Create Database from bacpac

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, bacpac

I am trying to create a new database on Azure via a bacpac file created by SQL Mgmt Studio. The bacpac has been saved to a BLOB storage. The process goes through all the way to the end however, the create fails with the following message

> BadRequest Argument 'userName' cannot be empty

The password has been entered, both automatically and manually, to no avail. I am stumped. Is this just a temporary Azure issue and I should keep trying or is something else I need to look at?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn’t explain the behavior described above - rather adds to the confusion. So, I tried going through Azure a couple of more times and no go. So I decided to connect to my Azure service through SQL Management Studio and added the database via the same bacpac file I tried using before and success. No problems or errors.

Would still like to know what is going on with the Azure interface, but as the saying goes, there’s more than one way to skin a cat.